# XAMPP vs WAMP security and other on Windows XP

Tags: security, windows-xp, xampp

Not long ago I found WAMP and thought it was a God send because it had all the things I wanted/needed (Apache, PHP, MySQL, and phpMyAdmin) all built into one installer.  One thing about WAMP has been making me mad is an error I get in phpMyAdmin about the advanced features not working.  I have tried to fix that error long enough on that error for long enough.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688385/problem-with-phpmyadmin-advanced-features

I now read that most people prefer XAMPP over WAMP, but I am a bit concerned that XAMPP might have some extra security holes with Mercury and Perl, two thing that I don't really need or want right now.

**Are my security concerns justified or not?**

**Is there any other reasons to go with XAMPP over WAMP or vice versa?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAMPP has suffered from very serious vulnerabilities in the past and their development team is slow to respond.  I know this from first hand experience because i have written an [exploit](http://milw0rm.com/exploits/7384) for XAMPP that can still be used even if Apache is firewalled off.  If you are concerned about secuirty the best approach is to an install method like [this](http://videolearn.net/manual-wamp-server-install/)  and only the components you absolutely need.  Every unnecessary process increases your attack surface,  and the likelihood of getting owned.

If your are doing php/mysql development on a windows XP system I recommend using VMWare to run Ubuntu.  I strongly prefer LAMP because it is easier to install and maintain.  To install lamp on an ubuntu system you type `sudo tasksel` and choose LAMP,  `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin` and your done!  Ubuntu 10.04 LTS has 10 years of support for patches, and security patches can be automatically installed.

Whatever method you use make sure to run [PHPSecInfo](http://phpsec.org/projects/phpsecinfo/) to help tune your configurations.  You shouldn't have *RED* in your report.  A web application firewall like [mod_secuirty](http://www.modsecurity.org/) also helps.